# Filtering view and workflows for lookup columns

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, lookup-column, filter, workflow-lookup

I have 2 lists with the following columns:

- **List A** - "Status" (choice column)/"Name"(Single line)/"ReqNr(Number)"
- **List B** - "StatusNameReq"(Lookupcolumn based on the columns in List A)

Now, I want to filter the view of ListB based on "StatusNameReq". To be precise, I want it to show items in the view only if in the "StatusNameReq" are contained the words "COMPLETED", "ARCHIVED", "CANCELED".

So, first of all, I created a new column in ListB called "Archive Status" as a choice column, with the options: ARCHIVED, CANCELED, OPEN, COMPLETED, APPROVAL.
Then, in SPD, I created a workflow that it's like this:

**If StatusNameReq contains COMPLETED**

**Set Archive Status to COMPLETED**
[image]

And so on for the other ones. In the view of ListB I then applied the filters like explained above (meaning, based on Archive Status).

*For some reason, it doesn't work. Can somebody help me out with this?*

I'm using SPD 2010 Workflows with SP 2013 (free version).

Comment: can you add screenshot of your workflow? are there after run some error or the WF only didnt anything?

Comment: And a screen shot of it...not working? It doesn't work is pretty much never helpful.  What does it do?  Do you see an error message?  Does it show too many items?  Too few?

Comment: Hi JoeMcShea, no error message, otherwise I would have uploaded it :) It just simply doesn't update my field "Archive Status", like nothing is happening...

Comment: Hi Zdeněk, I've added it in my original post